# how to use Vim to jump to the right place?

Tags: linux, vim, ctags

I'm using the Vim Ctags plugin,but I found that when I want to jump to the definition of a variable in a struct,it always jump to another struct's variable which the name is the same.How to fix that?
for example:

```
struct A
{
    int name_1;
    int name_2;
};
struct B
{
    int name_1;
    int name_3;
};

struct A a;
struct B b;
```

when I want to jump to the a.name_1,it jumps to the name_1 in struct B

Comment: Well, I think you need a plugin which can parse your source file. Maybe see [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete).

Comment: Or you can install ycm